# Can two IoT applications access a cellular modem at the same time so I don't have to kill ModemManager and lose my internet connection?

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, gps, modem

I'm having trouble getting GPS data from my modem consistently. Normally I can get the GPS in Python with the following code:

```py
import time
from serial import Serial

# If a "port" is given, then the port will be opened immediately.
ser = Serial(port="/dev/ttyUSB3", timeout=2, write_timeout=2)

# The following prints as "True"
print(ser.is_open)

def read_until_timeout(ser, timeout=5):
    """Turn GPS on and read until either we find the line we want, 
    or the timeout occurs
    """

    # Turn GPS on
    ser.write(b"AT+CGPS=1,1\r\n")

    # Request GPS
    ser.write(b"AT+CGPSINFO=1\r\n")

    # Start the loop
    time_start = time.time()
    while ((time.time() - time_start) < timeout):        
        print("Trying ser.readline().decode('ascii', errors='replace')...")
        try:
            # Read from the serial port
            line = ser.readline().decode('ascii', errors='replace')
        except serial.serialutil.SerialException as err:
            print(f"Problem reading data: {err}")

        if "+CGPSINFO:" in line:
            print(f"Found '+CGPSINFO:' in line: {line}")
            break
```

On a working gateway, that last print statement would return a line like the following, which contains the GPS latitude and longitude:

```
print(read_until_timeout(ser, timeout=5))
>>> '+CGPSINFO: 5100.506298,N,11404.432885,W,031120,234519.0,1080.1,0.0,204.6\r\n'
```

Sometimes the output from running this function is as follows, which I think just means the GPS can't get a "fix":

```py
print(read_until_timeout(ser, timeout=5))
>>> Found '+CGPSINFO:' in line: +CGPSINFO: ,,,,,,,,
```

But sometimes it says it's "busy" as follows:

```py
print(read_until_timeout(ser, timeout=5))
>>> Problem reading data: read failed: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

**Is the above because more than two applications can't access the serial port at the same time?**

If I try sending AT messages to the modem from Linux Bash, it says the modem is "busy"...

```
$ echo 'AT+CGPSINFO=1' | socat - /dev/ttyUSB3,crnl
>>> 2020/11/20 19:18:24 socat[3251] E open("/dev/ttyUSB3", 02002, 0666): Device or resource busy
```

So I check which devices are using the modem:

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/ttyUSB3
>>> COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ModemMana  800 root   12u   CHR  188,3      0t0  449 /dev/ttyUSB3
python    1706 root    3u   CHR  188,3      0t0  449 /dev/ttyUSB3
```

But if I shut down [ModemManager](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/) with `sudo kill 800` the cellular internet connection dies, and I can't have that because these are remote IoT devices far in the wilderness (I have about 50 of them in operation around North America).

**Is there a way to *share* the modem with ModemManager so I can access the GPS results from Python or from the shell, while on a cellular internet connection?**

This question is related so I put a bounty on it too:
https://superuser.com/questions/1455327/trying-to-read-a-serial-port-device-or-resource-busy

**Update Nov 22, 2020:**

@GitFront helpfully [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64954813/3385948) using ModemManager directly. Great suggestion. Neat trick with the `gi` library too.

From Ubuntu Bash, here's what I get when I try to get the GPS from ModemManager directly:

```
user@user-Default-string:~$ mmcli -m 0 --location-status

/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
  ----------------------------
  Location |   capabilities: '3gpp-lac-ci'
           |        enabled: '3gpp-lac-ci'
           |        signals: 'no'
```

Notice under location capabilities, no `gps-raw, gps-nmea, agps` shows up for some reason, only `3gpp-lac-ci`, but I know this gateway/SIMCom 7600 modem has GPS/GNSS capabilities, and it's got a passive antenna hooked up properly.

**Does anyone know why `gps-raw, gps-nmea, agps` are not showing up as capabilities?**

The exact same gateway/modem/antenna combination in my office does have `gps-raw, gps-nmea, agps` capabilities, and everything works perfectly for it... The only difference is the SIM card, which should not matter. The gateway in my office reports the following capabilities, by contrast:

```
user@ax1000008:~$ mmcli -m 0 --location-status
  ------------------------
  Location | capabilities: 3gpp-lac-ci, gps-raw, gps-nmea, agps
           |      enabled: 3gpp-lac-ci
           |      signals: no
  ------------------------
  GPS      | refresh rate: 30 seconds
```

I request to enable `gps-raw, gps-nmea` with:

```
user@ax1000008:~$ sudo mmcli -m 0 --location-enable-gps-raw --location-enable-gps-nmea
successfully setup location gathering
```

Then I request the GPS successfully (on the gateway/modem in my office...) with:

```
user@ax1000008:~$ sudo mmcli -m 0 --location-get
  --------------------------
  3GPP |      operator code: 302
       |      operator name: 220
       | location area code: 2BC4
       | tracking area code: 0000
       |            cell id: 04B68931
  --------------------------
  GPS  |               nmea:
       |                     $GPGGA,183553.00,5100.511216,N,11404.429721,W,1,06,1.7,1078.0,M,-16.0,M,,*6C
       |                     $GPRMC,183552.00,A,5100.511138,N,11404.429729,W,0.0,341.3,221120,15.4,E,A*10
       |                     $GPGSA,A,2,01,03,21,22,31,32,,,,,,,2.0,1.7,0.9*3C
       |                     $GPGSV,4,1,15,01,45,295,34,03,11,291,29,10,31,109,20,11,,,36*4F
       |                     $GPGSV,4,2,15,12,08,056,19,21,53,258,35,22,33,292,32,23,02,111,15*79
       |                     $GPGSV,4,3,15,25,06,092,22,31,33,163,23,32,70,066,33,08,02,236,*7C
       |                     $GPGSV,4,4,15,17,04,344,,20,,,,24,,,*48
       |                     $GPVTG,341.3,T,325.9,M,0.0,N,0.0,K,A*2B
       |                     $PQXFI,183553.0,5100.511216,N,11404.429721,W,1078.0,9.61,5.64,0.13*4E
       |                utc: 183553.00
       |          longitude: -114.073829
       |           latitude: 51.008520
       |           altitude: 1078.000000
```

On the non-working gateway in the field, here's what I get when I try to enable `gps-raw` and `gps-nmea`:

```
user@user-Default-string:~$ sudo mmcli -m 0 --location-enable-gps-raw --location-enable-gps-nmea
error: couldn't setup location gathering: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Unsupported: Cannot enable unsupported location sources: 'gps-raw, gps-nmea''
```

Comment: What modem is it?  I've used a Telit modem before, and one of the serial ports that it provides is a dedicated NMEA port, which I then hooked up to `gpsd`.

Comment: @rm5248 It's a [SIMCom SIM7600](https://www.simcom.com/product/SIM7600X.html). It does have a dedicated NMEA port actually. If I run `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB1 | grep GPGGA` I get line after line of `$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66`. Does that mean it's just not getting a fix? It's been like that for days...

Comment: That does look like it can't get a fix - I wonder if that's what the error message about "unsupported location sources" comes in.  Maybe it can only enable location sources when the data is valid?  There are also many possible things that can go wrong with GPS(bad cabling, bad sky view, etc.)

Comment: @rm5248 Just a quick idea: if you just need to read the output from the GPS, you could use a tool like [slsnif](https://linux.die.net/man/1/slsnif), then reading the logged output from python.

Comment: Looks like a hardware or driver issue. Is the hardware and driver between your two examples the exact same revision? A hardware model can have a revision that changes behavior slightly, and so can the related driver.

Comment: @HackSlash that's helpful. I noticed ModemManager is a different version on the two different gateways, and it's working properly on the version that's updated to v1.10.0 and not on v1.6.8. Not sure how to check the hardware version exactly

Comment: @SeanMcCarthy The hardware revision would need to be printed somewhere near the model# on the device which is up to the manufacturer. You could contact them to ask about different versions of that model. Start by updating the driver versions to match as that's the easiest course of action.

Comment: @HackSlash I checked with `mmcli -m 0` and they're showing the same model/revision. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've mostly figured it out now, without having to kill ModemManager (which risks killing the internet connection on the IoT remote gateways).

The main answer is that I'm simply not getting a GPS fix (permissions issues aside).

I wasn't doing anything wrong in my Python code, and sometimes ModemManager was using the AT port I was sending commands to (either `/dev/ttyUSB2` or `/dev/ttyUSB3`)... Upgrading ModemManager to v1.10.0 also might work, but I'm reluctant to do that on a live gateway working in the field.

@rm5248 suggested using the dedicated NMEA port at `/dev/ttyUSB1` on a SIMCom 7600 like mine, and he was right, I think.

I installed GPSD (GPSDaemon) and the various clients for it (e.g. cgps and gpsmon) using this [documentation](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/installation.html#_installing_gpsd). GPSD and its clients are excellent for getting GPS info, if the GPS has a fix.

How to test the GPSD software:
https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/installation.html#_how_to_test_the_software

```sh
# Start GPSD on /dev/ttyUSB1 with debug level 5, 
# -N (don't daemonize), and -n (don't wait for 
# client to connect to poll GPS)

# no daemon, for debugging
$ sudo gpsd -D 5 -N -n /dev/ttyUSB1

# daemonized to run in background
$ sudo gpsd -D 5 -n /dev/ttyUSB1
```

Then run one of the following two clients and watch the dedicated NMEA port on `/dev/ttyUSB1`, as opposed to an "AT" port at `/dev/ttyUSB2` or `/dev/ttyUSB3`:

```
$ cgps
$ gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB1
```

On a working gateway `cgps` works like this:
[image: working gps on gateway with cgps]

And `gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB1` works like this:
[image: working gps on gateway with gpsmon]

But on a non-working gateway `cgps` looks like this, showing `NO FIX`:
[image: non-working gateway, no fix]

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to utilize ModemManager to get the GPS location instead of getting it directly. This way you can avoid using the same serial port from two services.

There is documentation on how to do this from the command line using the `mmcli` tool in the ModemManager manpage:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/man/1.0.0/mmcli.8.html#lbBC

There is also a `libmm-glib` library which you should be able to use from Python via GObject Introspection without running the command line tool.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('ModemManager', '1.0')
from gi.repository import ModemManager
```

Keep in mind that your device may not be able to provide the location while a data session is active ([from the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Location.html)):

> The Location interface allows devices to provide location information to client applications. Not all devices can provide this information, or even if they do, they may not be able to provide it while a data session is active.

Comment: thanks for the helpful suggestion. I've updated my question with the results of using ModemManager directly. Any ideas now?